# Warlock's Create thrall doesn't get a saving throw even if the target takes damage? What kind of enchantment spell is it?

Tags: dnd-5e

Warlock having a Great Old one as a Patron upon reaching 14th level unlocks the ability to Create Thrall by charming an incapacitated humanoid.
The power as it is written looks like it uses the Dominate Person spell as its basis.

It states the same wording of "You communicate telepathically with the charmed creature as long the two of you are in the same plane of existence". (Thus my reasoning).

The question though is this. Does the charmed creature get a saving throw when it takes damage as per the spell Dominate Person in order to get a chance to remove the condition, or its condition of charmed in this case is removed only and only when a remove curse is cast on it or you use this ability on some other creature again?

Finally because the text on the Create Thrall doesn't tell us what kind of enchantment this ability is another question would be: if this ability is not based on dominate person would it be based of the spell Charm person? And why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Spells and abilities in D&D 5e do exactly what they say they do. Create Thrall says that:

> The creature is then charmed by you until a *remove curse* spell is cast on it, the charmed condition is removed from it, or you use this feature again.

So no, taking damage will not give the target a saving throw. Only *remove curse*, something that removes the Charmed condition (such as *mind blank*), or you using the feature again will end the effect.

And once again, the ability does exactly what it says it does. It says nothing about being based off another spell, so it isn't. It has nothing to do with *charm person* or *dominate person*, regardless of anything it has in common with either of them.

If you're wondering about the actual effect of Create Thrall, it gives the creature the charmed condition and allows you to communicate telepathically with them. That's all it says it does, so that's all it does. The effects of the Charmed condition are:

> - A charmed creature can't attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects.
> - The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

Comment: Note that this, for example, doesn't prevent the thrall from calling the police on you, hating you, and taking out a contract on your life with the local assassin's guild.  Or directly fighting and killing you with a variety of harmful effects, like fireballs, falling objects, or drowning.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer actually they cannot directly fight or kill you, as directly per the charmed condition, they can use nothing harmful on you

Comment: This answer is in accordance with Mike Mearls’ tweet on Sage Advice: http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/07/06/does-create-thrall-actually-obeys-you/