# How does Create Thrall, the Great Old One Warlock feature, work in Adventurers League play?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, dnd-adventurers-league, mind-control

When a [Great Old One Warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheGreatOldOne) uses the Create Thrall feature (PHB, p. 110) in Adventurers League play, does the Thrall work with you?  Does it persist through sessions?  Is there any guidance on how this works?

Comment: [Related question which you might find useful.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63489/15469) It's probably not a duplicate, since it doesn't cover how long the effect lasts in AL.

Answer (score 8):

Scanning through the [AL PG](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/ALPGv82.pdf), [AL DMG](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/ALDMGv82.pdf), and [AL FAQ](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/FAQv82.pdf) documents ([see here for the latest versions](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack)), there doesn't appear to be any specific guidance on this, which likely puts it in DM discretion territory.

The *Detect Thoughts* document hosted on dndadventurersleague.com is a compilation of rulings made by AL admins and such, and the [latest version (1.4)](http://dndadventurersleague.org/detect-thoughts-volume-1-4/) says:

> *Do spell effects carry over between AL sessions?*
>
> The AL guidelines do not currently hold an official position, so this will be a decision between players and their DMs.

Of course, Create Thrall is a class feature and not a spell, but I can't imagine the situation is any different in the absence of a ruling that says otherwise (like the guidance on Wish, for example). Having the effect of create thrall persist over multiple sessions only really makes any sense in the context of a hardcover where the same NPC/creature you've made into a thrall is going to be present session after session. In that case, I suspect most reasonable DMs will let the effect persist as long as you remain in that hardcover.

On the other hand, playing a module and trying to make use of a thrall you created outside of that module would be very strange, and I suspect most DMs would not allow it (even if it was a module in the same setting as the original use of Create Thrall).

Comment: Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). Rather than adding an edit note with the links at the end of your post, you should edit your answer as a whole to stand as if it were always the best version of itself. I've done it for you this time :)